# php - не создается zip архив

Tags: php, zip

При создании zip архива в том же каталоге нет никаких ошибок, но архив не создается. В php.ini все включено. Пользуюсь wamp сервером. Пример кода:

```
<?php

$zip=new ZipArchive ();
$zip->open ("test.zip", ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что в ***том же*** каталоге? Попробуйте прописать абсолютный путь или поиском по всем папкам поискать Ваш архив.

Comment: дак вы пустой архив создаете.

Comment: Добавьте закрытие и сохранение, а также проверку на успешность: ` if (!$zip->close()) echo error_get_last(); ` возможно нету прав на создание

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если мне не изменяет память, то вы только открыли архив, чтобы с ним работать как с новым. И чтобы сохранить архив, в него надо что-нибудь положить.

```
<?php

$zip = new ZipArchive ();

$zip->open ("test.zip", ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
$zip->addFromString('test.txt', 'файл txt'); // создаст файл test.txt
$zip->close();
```

И только если вы что-нибудь положите в архив, он будет создан. Иначе нет.

Answer (score 1):

Хочу добавить, что многие также могут столкнуться с проблемой, когда код написан как в примерах (создали объект класса, открыли новый архив, записали данные и закрыли архив), а архив не создается (речь идет о проблеме в ОС Windows). Вот такой код у меня был сначала (он не создавал новый архив):

```
$archive = new ZipArchive;

if($archive->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE) === true)
{
    $dir = opendir($temp_files_dir);

    while($file = readdir($dir))
    {
        $archive->addFile($temp_files_dir.$file, $file);
    }

    $archive->close();
    //exit("Success");
}
else
{
    exit("Error open");
}
```

Если раскомментировать строку "exit("Success");", то при запуске такого кода лично у меня отображается следующее:

> Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Can't open file: Permission denied in
> C:\Server\data\htdocs\collection_unloading\Service\require\create_archive.php
> on line 276

> Success

Несколько дней мучался с этой проблемой. А решение оказалось совершенно простым. Когда просматриваешь директорию, в которой лежат только файлы, с помощью проводника Windows, видишь только файлы. Но когда функция readdir просматривает и возвращает текущий элемент указанной директории, выяснилось, что перед файлами она возвращает 2 директории: "." и "..". И вот из-за них такая ошибка и появлялась. Поэтому решением этой проблемы послужило условие обхода этих директорий:

```
if($file != "." && $file != '..')
```

Следующий код заработал как надо:

```
$archive = new ZipArchive;
if($archive->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE) === true)
{
    $dir = opendir($temp_files_dir);

    while($file = readdir($dir))
    {
        if($file != "." && $file != '..')
        {
            $archive->addFile($temp_files_dir.$file, $file);
        }
    }

    $archive->close();
}
else
{
    exit("Error open");
}
```